# Configuring TALISMAN with superset helm

Tags: python, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

So I'm in the process of configuring my superset deployment with helm. Everything works fine aside from the warning regarding Talisman, which I really want to configure to get rid of. i.e.:

> WARNING:superset.initialization:We haven't found any Content Security Policy (CSP) defined in the configurations. Please make sure to configure CSP using the TALISMAN_ENABLED and TALISMAN_CONFIG keys or any other external software. Failing to configure CSP have serious security implications. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP for more information. You can disable this warning using the CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_WARNING key.

It is not completely clear to me how I actually hook into the `config.py` to override existing Talisman configs. From the docs it seems as if it would be possible to do something like:

```
configOverrides:

  security: |
    TALISMAN_ENABLED = True
    TALISMAN_CONFIG = {
    ...
    }
```

But that doesn't really do the trick. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As per the source code of config.py

```
TALISMAN_ENABLED = utils.cast_to_boolean(os.environ.get("TALISMAN_ENABLED", True))
```

So all you need to do is pass that as an environment variable in Helm chart values.

for eg,

in values.yaml

```
# -- Extra environment variables that will be passed into pods
extraEnv: 
  TALISMAN_ENABLED : False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean value just like this, hopefully it'll works! `TALISMAN_ENABLED = False`